# How do I run my app with large pages in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Large pages are available in `Windows Server 2003` and `Windows Vista`.

But how do I enable large pages for my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin's answer is correct on Windows Server 2003:

> You will have to assign the "Lock pages in memory" privilege to any user that runs your > application. This includes administrators
>
> 1. Select Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy
> 2. Select Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment
> 3. Double click "Lock pages in memory", add users and/or groups
> 4. Reboot the machine

On Windows Vista you need also make sure that the application is run as Administrator (by right-clicking on the application or the shell and choosing "Run as adminstrator".

In addition, it helps to have a freshly booted machine since the large pages can "run out" due to fragmentation of the heap.

Comment: It's possible to "run out" but I am pretty certain I have seen Vista and 2008 doing a lot of swapping to disk when a bunch of large pages are requested, so I believe they use swap to clean out fragments.

Comment: +1 for the comment on running as administrator! Needed on Windows 7 too.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to assign the `Lock pages in memory` privilege to any user that runs your application.  This includes administrators.

1. Select Control **Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security** Policy
2. Select Local **Policies -> User Rights Assignment**
3. Double click "Lock pages in memory", add users and/or groups
4. Reboot the machine